# Multi module gradle: how to run module A before compiling modules B in a multi module project

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

We have a multi-module project in gradle.  We have a "data" module that needs to be compiled (simple java 11 app) then run.

When we run `java -jar data.jar` after compiling the data module source is generated into the "webapp" module.  With this generated source code we are now able to build the webapp module.

I am new to Gradle and struggling to figure out how do achieve this properly.  I am especially concerned if I do it wrong I will make build caching fail.

Note: I am using Kotlin with Gradle 7.5.

Comment: I'm not quite clear on what you want to achieve, but have you seen the Gradle documentation on [sharing dependencies between subprojects](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies_between_subprojects.html)? If so, and it still doesn't work, can you update your question to include some build config?

Answer (score 0):

The answer appears to be to create a custom configuration which produces a different artifact than the default.

task(taskJarGenerated, Jar::class) {
group = groupJooq
dependsOn(taskCompileGeneratedSource)

```
inputs.dir("$projectDir/build/classes/java/main")
outputs.file("${projectDir}/build/libs/data-1.0.jar")

from("$projectDir/build/classes/java/main")
```

}

artifacts {
add("generatedDbDataJar", tasks[taskJarGenerated])
}

Then you can reference this custom configuration "generatedDbDataJar" in other projects like this:

```
dependencies {
    implementation(project(":data","generatedDbDataJar"))
}
```